# Excel dropdown list values based on differt value in table

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, formula

I have the following table:

```
    A            B
1 Fruit        Apple
2 Fruit        Banana
3 Meat         Steak
4 Vegetable    Carrot
5 Meat         Hamburger
6 Fruit        Orange
```

I wish to create a dropdown list of the values in B grouped by the unique values in A. I already managed to create a dropdown list with the unique values of A, so if a user selects one of the values in the dropdown of A, I wish to get the have its corresponding values from B. Example:

```
    X         Y
1 Fruit     +Apple
            +Banana
            +Orange

2 Meat      +Steak
            +Hamburger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Index/Small` formula to get what you're looking for.  Having the data validations in one column, with the results in another, is a little tricky, since the "B" range will be dynamic.  However, this should give you a good starting place.

If your Data Validation choice is in A1, you can enter this (and drag down) in B1:

`=INDEX($F$1:$F$6,SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$6=$A$1,ROW($F$1:$F$6)-ROW($F$1)+1),ROWS(F$1:F1)))`

Enter that with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

Note you'll want to change your ranges to match where the data is.  This is how it looks/works on my sheet:

[image]

And to hide that `#NUM` error, just wrap `=IfError([formula],"")` around it: 
`=IfError(INDEX($F$1:$F$6,SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$6=$A$1,ROW($F$1:$F$6)-ROW($F$1)+1),ROWS(F$1:F1))),"")`